# Старые версии дистрибутивов Bitrix

Tags: php, windows, битрикс, поиск-программ, ресурсы

Где можно скачать старые дистрибутивы битрикс для версии **php 7.4 и младше**?

Вопрос возник в связи [Установка на php 8](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic153708/)

@ssv32 пытался https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1+%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.1c-bitrix.ru%2F&newwindow=1&sca_esv=575211775&sxsrf=AM9HkKmKcfWduxrPK7qe96LSvnVOZQ0TsQ%3A1697817391366&source=hp&ei=L6MyZfP_E6_XwPAPueyhOA&iflsig=AO6bgOgAAAAAZTKxP_CIUy7B72N0QDjJBklfaL1lYPlz&ved=0ahUKEwiz04PU_oSCAxWvKxAIHTl2CAcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1+%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.1c-bitrix.ru%2F&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IivQstC10LEg0LDRgNGF0LjQsiBodHRwczovL3d3dy4xYy1iaXRyaXgucnUvSOlvUABYmWhwAHgAkAEAmAGoAaABjQmqAQM2LjW4AQPIAQD4AQH4AQLCAgcQIxiKBRgnwgIREC4YgAQYsQMYgwEYxwEY0QPCAhEQLhiDARjHARixAxjRAxiABMICCxAAGIAEGLEDGIMBwgINEAAYigUYsQMYgwEYQ8ICCxAuGIoFGLEDGIMBwgIHEAAYigUYQ8ICCxAuGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIFEAAYgATCAggQABiABBixA8ICDxAAGIoFGLEDGIMBGAoYQ8ICChAAGIAEGBQYhwLCAg0QLhiABBjHARivARgK&sclient=gws-wiz#ip=1 - не нашел

Comment: 1. Определитесь с версией битрикса, найдите историю изменений например главного модуля, запомните дату когда она была (год месяц). 2. Наберите в поиске гугл например "веб архив", на одном из сайтов выдачи (там пару мест точно есть) укажите офф. сайт битрикса, выберите интересующую дату и попадите на вкладку сказать продукт и скачайте. (проверено, доставал старую версию так).

Comment: “Вопрос возник в связи Установка на php 8” – что бы установить последнию версию, перед  первым шагом установки поправьте функцию getStringByCharsets как сказано на форуме, и откатите правку после установки.

Comment: попробуйте тут `https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/1c-bitrix.ru`  скачать, а с датой определиться тут `https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/docs/versions.php?lang=ru&module=main`